# Why Soccer game slips right past halftime and 1st half stoppage time Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure a way to get 3 minutes of stoppage time without copying and pasting the whole code into an extra 3 minute sequence.  The rest of the code works well except when I inserted the fsthalf = fsthalf - 3. That's when the code skipped over halftime and full time. Otherwise the code works decently. Any suggestions?

```
import random
import time

pscore = 0
cscore = 0
fsthalf = 0
extrafst = 0
extrasec = 0

Player1 = input("Enter 1 or 2 =")
Player2 = input("Enter 1 or 2 =")
Player3 = input("Enter 1, 2, or 3 =")
Player4 = input("Enter 1, 2, 3, or 4 =")
cpu1 = ["1", "2"]
cpu2 = ["1", "2"]
cpu3 = ["1", "2", "3"]
cpu4 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
cpu4 = ("1", "2", "3", "4")
run = ["1", "2"]
pass1 = ["1", "2"]
pass2 = ["1", "2", "3"]
shot = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

half = True
while half:
   if fsthalf == 45 + 3:
       print("Halftime")
       time.sleep(2)
       fsthalf == fsthalf - 3
   if Player1 == random.choice(run):
        print("Player has the ball")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Player makes a run")
        fsthalf = fsthalf + 1
        print("time", fsthalf)
        if Player2 == random.choice(pass1):
            print("Player Pass connects")
            if Player3 == random.choice(pass2):
                print("Great pass in the box")
                if Player4 == random.choice(shot):
                    print("Goooooal!!!")
                    pscore = pscore + 1
                    print("Player", pscore)
                    print("CPU", cscore)
                elif Player4 != random.choice(shot):
                    print("What A Save By CPU!")
                    pass
            elif Player3 != random.choice(pass2):
                print("Player Pass stolen")
                pass
        elif Player2 != random.choice(pass1):
            print("Player turnover on pass")
            pass
   elif Player1 != random.choice(run):
       print("Player Turnover at Midfield!")
       time.sleep(1)
       pass
   if random.choice(cpu1) == random.choice(run):
       print("CPU has the ball")
       time.sleep(1)
       print("CPU makes a run")
       fsthalf = fsthalf + 1
       print("time", fsthalf)
       if random.choice(cpu2) == random.choice(pass1):
           print("CPU Pass connects")
           if random.choice(cpu3) == random.choice(pass2):
               print("Great pass in the box")
               if random.choice(cpu4) == random.choice(shot):
                   print("Goooooal!!!")
                   cscore = cscore + 1
                   print("Player", pscore)
                   print("CPU", cscore)
               elif random.choice(cpu4) != random.choice(shot):
                   print("What A Save By Player!")
                   pass
           elif random.choice(cpu3) != random.choice(pass2):
               print("CPU Pass stolen")
               pass
           elif random.choice(cpu2) != random.choice(pass1):
               print("CPU turnover on pass")
               pass
       elif random.choice(cpu1) != random.choice(run):
           print("CPU Turnover at Midfield!")
           time.sleep(1)
           pass
   if fsthalf == 90 + 3:
       print("Full Time!")
       print("Player", pscore)
       print("CPU", cscore)
       half = False
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it has something to do with the fact that your code says `fsthalf == fsthalf - 3` instead of `fsthalf = fsthalf - 3`

Comment: I know there's still a couple more bugs I'm trying to work out, but I'll just leave out 1st half stoppage for now. It isn't really working or even displaying "Halftime"